# ¿Como mostrar una nube de dialogo en Unity?

Tags: unity3d, unity

Verán, estoy haciendo un juego en Unity pero no sé como hacer el Script para hacer que encima del personaje aparezca una nubecita, tengo ya la textura de la nube pero quiero hacer que cuando me acerque mucho aparezca la nube y mire siempre a cámara.Si saben como hacerlo me podrían explicar la estructura?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto seria una manera de hacerlo.
Yo de ejemplo puse el nombre del tag como Activador, pero puedes hacerlo también con nombre, poniendo el nombre del gameobject que lo active.

Codigo:

```
...
using UnityEngine.UI;

public GameObject Nube;

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll){ 
if(coll.gameobject.tag == "Activador")   // El nombre del tag es el que le pusiste al                                     
{                                        // GameObject, también lo puedes hacer con 
                                         // name
 Nube.SetActive(true);                      
}
} 
void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collexit){
if(collexit.gameobject.tag == "Activador")
{
Nube.SetActive(false);
}
}
}
```

Lo que hace este código es simplemente que activa la nube cuando toca el Collider y cuando sale lo desactiva. 
(La nube tienes que ponerla en el canvas como imagen)
(Ten en cuenta poner el sprite limite, osea donde quieres que se active la nube)
Espero que te sirva.
Saludos.